# React-Redux Typescript, types for reducer actions errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm transforming my react app to Typescript and I've run into the problem with types of actions in the reducer.

I'm having an error when I use Discriminated Unions, for example on the action ADD_TO_CART, when I have multiple declarations in Discriminated Unions it shows me an error

```
Property 'product' does not exist on type 'ICart | IProduct | { products: IProduct[]; } | IOrder'.
  Property 'product' does not exist on type 'IProduct'.ts(2339)
```

When I delete all the other action types and only leave ADD_TO_CART the error is gone from typescript. How can I declare my actions so it doesn't show an error?

the same goes for other types for example GET_PRODUCTS when I delete all the other types from Discriminated Unions and only leave GET_PRODUCTS the error is gone but when I declare all the actions it shows:

```
Property 'products' does not exist on type 'ICart | IProduct | { products: IProduct[]; } | IOrder'.
  Property 'products' does not exist on type 'ICart'.ts(2339)
```

## MY TYPES - declarations file

```
export interface IArticle {
  _id: string,
  title: string,
  shortDescription: string,
  content: string,
  author: string,
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
}

export interface IProduct {
  _id: string,
  title: string,
  category: string,
  shortDescription: string,
  description: string,
  photo: {
    fileName: string,
    url: string,
  },
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
}

export interface ICart {
  product: IProduct,
  qty: number,
}

export interface IOrder {
  nr: number,
  products: object,
  user: string | IUser,
  status: string,
  comment: string,
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
}
```

MY REDUCER

```
import {
  ADD_TO_CART, GET_PRODUCTS, DELETE_FROM_CART, ADD_ORDER, GET_ORDERS, GET_ONE_ORDER,
  CLEAR_ONE_ORDER, ARCHIVE_ORDER, GET_ARCHIVED_ORDERS, GET_ONE_ARCHIVED_ORDER,
  CLEAR_ONE_ARCHIVED_ORDER, GET_ORDERS_ADMIN, START_ORDER, GET_RECAP_ADMIN,
} from '../actions/types.action';
import { IProduct, IOrder, ICart } from '../declarations';

const initialState = {
  products: [],
  isLoading: true,
  cart: {},
  orders: [],
  adminOrders: [],
  recapLoading: true,
  recapAdmin: null,
  archivedOrders: [],
  archivedOrdersLoading: true,
  oneArchivedOrder: null,
  oneArchivedOrderLoading: true,
  cartLength: null,
  oneOrder: null,
  oneOrderLoading: true,
  backdropOpen: false,
};

type ACTIONTYPE =
| { type: 'ADD_TO_CART'; payload: ICart }
| { type: 'GET_PRODUCTS'; payload: { products: IProduct[] } }
| { type: 'DELETE_FROM_CART'; payload: IProduct }
| { type: 'ADD_ORDER'; payload: null }
| { type: 'GET_ORDERS'; payload: null }
| { type: 'GET_ONE_ORDER'; payload: null }
| { type: 'CLEAR_ONE_ORDER'; payload: null }
| { type: 'ARCHIVE_ORDER'; payload: IOrder }
| { type: 'GET_ARCHIVED_ORDERS'; payload: null }
| { type: 'GET_ONE_ARCHIVED_ORDER'; payload: null }
| { type: 'CLEAR_ONE_ARCHIVED_ORDER'; payload: null }
| { type: 'GET_ORDERS_ADMIN'; payload: null }
| { type: 'START_ORDER'; payload: null }
| { type: 'GET_RECAP_ADMIN'; payload: null };

export default function (state = initialState, action: ACTIONTYPE) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: {
          ...state.cart,
          [payload?.product?._id]: {
            product: payload.product,
            qty: payload.qty,
          },
        },
      };
    case DELETE_FROM_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: update(state.cart, {
          $unset: [payload],
        }),
      };
    case GET_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: payload.products,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case GET_RECAP_ADMIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        recapAdmin: payload,
        recapLoading: false,
      };
    case ADD_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: {},
        backdropOpen: false,
      };
    case START_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        backdropOpen: true,
      };
    case GET_ORDERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        orders: payload,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case GET_ONE_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        oneOrder: payload,
        oneOrderLoading: false,
      };
    case CLEAR_ONE_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        oneOrder: null,
        oneOrderLoading: true,
      };
    case ARCHIVE_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        orders: state.orders.filter((o) => o._id !== payload?._id),
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case GET_ARCHIVED_ORDERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        archivedOrders: payload,
        archivedOrdersLoading: false,
      };
    case GET_ONE_ARCHIVED_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        oneArchivedOrder: payload,
        oneArchivedOrderLoading: false,
      };
    case CLEAR_ONE_ARCHIVED_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        oneArchivedOrder: null,
        oneArchivedOrderLoading: true,
      };
    case GET_ORDERS_ADMIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        adminOrders: payload,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We specifically recommend [*not* trying to create TS union types of your Redux actions](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#avoid-action-type-unions).  Also, you shouldn't have to write any separate action creators or action types by hand, because [our official Redux Toolkit package does all that work for you automatically](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-createslice).

So, in this case the best approach is to rewrite this logic using Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` API, which will both avoid the type issues, simplify the logic, and remove the need for all those hand-written actions.

Comment: Thank you for this response, as many tutorials on the web recommending using union types.

Comment: Yup, and unfortunately most Redux tutorials outside our official docs are _very_ outdated and show practices we do not recommend.